# Pseudo-assembly for loading a certain numbers of 0's to an address

Tags: assembly, copy

> Use ‘pseudo assembly language’ to represent code that will: initialise
>   the AX, BX and CX registers to zero; store 0xFEAD in the DX register;
>   and copy a block of 1024 zeroes to memory starting at address 0xF000. Explain why this initialization code is insufficient to allow any use of subroutines or interrupt services routines.

I've been given this exercise. The lecturer wants pseudo-assembly.

I've gotten this far:

```
mov 0, ax
mov 0, bx
mov 0, cx
mov 0xFEAD, dx
```

I'm supposed to google how to

> copy a block of 1024 zeroes to memory starting at address 0xF000

but could not find what I was looking for (probably cause I don't know the asm I'm looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to guess based on the conventions of assembly and the syntax you've shown here, I'd suggest doing something like

```
mov 0, si
.loop:
mov 0, 0xF000(si)
add 4, si
cmp si, 0x400
je  .loop
```

It's just a translation of a for loop like you would find in C.  We initialize the `si` register to `0`, then we set the region of memory found at `0xF000 + si`, increment `si` by `4` (which seems to be the register size you're using), and repeat until we've set `0x400` bytes (a.k.a. 1024 bytes).

The `je` instruction is the conventional "Jump if equal" instruction.

Comment: Thank you, for that. si is not usually an actual register no? I should pick a register that actually exists like ax and reset it to 0 at the end?

Comment: @Juicy Sure! Although `si` is often an actual register, but go ahead and change it just to be on the safe side of what your prof expects.

Comment: I've been digging my head to answer the second part of the question. The part we're studying is the initialization process of a PC and we've seen examples of MBR code. Do you have any idea why this would be insufficient to allow the use of subroutines and interrupts? To me all this code does is set registers to 0 and a bit of memory to 0. The question is really cryptic to me!

Comment: @Juicy You're over thinking it! The answer is very simple, and you even said it in your comment without realizing it.  Try asking yourself: "Is there a way for me to create a subroutine or an interrupt using only these instructions?"

Comment: No because we're not using a stack pointer and a base pointer, so we can't keep track of a next instruction to return to if we called a subroutine or got interrupted? No push/pop ?

Comment: @Juicy it makes sense, it's perfectly reasonable but we can simulate the stack pointer and base pointer using other registers... What other pointer is there that we can't simulate and has to do with keeping track of the next instruction? Hint: in your syntax it would be called `ip`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43371/discussion-between-juicy-and-randomusername)

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd want to set up some sort of loop.  So pick a register to store either however many zeros you've written or however many zeros are left.  And another register to store the base address.  In each iteration of the loop, you'd want to  write some zeros, adjust your counter register and see if you're done.

(* Search for mov byte ptr for the syntax of how to approach writing to memory.  You can include both a base address and an offset in a byte ptr expression
* You can subtract or add from a variable which will set the flags register
* you can use flags changes to conditionally jump; see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow) for discussions of the conditional jump instructions

Whether you choose to count up or down will affect how easy the jump at the end of the loop is.

I hope I've done a reasonable job of balancing giving you things to look at against not doing the exercise for you; I don't have a lot of experience at that and sorry if I got the balance wrong.